# Foreign key shows wrong field in dropdownlis in dynamic data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

Foreign key fields in Dynamic Data show the next char field of the child table in dropdownlist. How can I tell it to show another field?

Assume these tables:
Personnel(PKPersonnelID, PersonnelName, FKDepartmentID)
Department(PKDepartmentID, Description, Department)

FKDepartmentID in Personnel table is a foreign key to Department table. When I want to insert new record to Personnel, Dynamic Data shows me a DropDownList for FKDepartmentID. In this DropDownList the values from Description field are displayed(As I recognized it shows the first char field after the primary key). But I want to show Department field values.

Answer (score 0):

The code where you are binding the data with the drop down list, can you please show it over here, let say your drop down list Id is drpDepartment, than make your binding like:

```
drpDepartment.DataTextField = "Department";
drpDepartment.DataValueField = "PKDepartmentID";
drpDepartment.DataSource = YOURCOLLECTION OR DATASOURCE;
drpDepartment.DataBind();
```

Comment: Oh I see, sorry dear have no idea of it, if you can't find any solution to it than you can change the sequence of columns in your database :)